# Salvar os resultados de uma query em csv - Hive do HortonWorks

Tags: csv, hive

Por favor, eu tentei o código abaixo no Hive 1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292 e houve um erro. Como eu posso extrair os dados de uma query em um csv sem criar uma tabela?

```
hive --e 'select * from product limit 10;' | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' > ~/output.csv;
```

Erro:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'hive' '<EOF>' '<EOF>'
```

Answer (score 0):

O comando está correto.

O host que vc esta acessando tem o client do Hive instalado?

O que vc pode fazer tambem é entrar no hive e fazer um insert local directory, como no exemplo abaixo. Ele vai salvador o resultado no host linux q vc esta conectado.

Caso prefira uma interface gráfica para fazer isso, vc pode instalar o dbeaver (https://dbeaver.io/download/)

```
insert overwrite local directory '/tmp/output' 
select * from product limit 10;
```

Comment: Atenção com a formatação de código para que fiquem legíveis